# How to get Base64 from ajax Post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, webmethod

I was trying to get the base64 post in my codebehind webmethod, 
but it seems like everytime I include the base64 I get an error : the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) - it keeps on hitting the error function.
The Post works with the other strings when the base64 is not inlcuded int the data that im passing.

```
function event_create() {
        alert("alert test : function works => onclick");

        function getBase64(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = function () {
                console.log(reader.result);
            };
            reader.onerror = function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
            };
        }


        var eventTitle = $("#eventTitle").val();
        var eventDesc = $("#eventDesc").val();
        var eventTimeStart = $("#eventTimeStart").val();
        var eventTimeEnd = $("#eventTimeEnd").val();
        var eventDateStart = $("#eventDateStart").val();
        var eventDateEnd = $("#eventDateEnd").val();
        var eventType = $("#eventType").val();
        var eventPlace = $("#eventPlace").val();
        var eventAttendee = document.getElementById("lblSelected").innerText;
        var userID = sessionStorage.getItem("userID");
        var imageBase64 = getBase64(document.getElementById('test').files[0]);

        var data = { 'eventTitle': eventTitle, 'eventDesc': eventDesc, 'eventPlace': eventPlace, 'eventType': eventType, 'eventAttendee': eventAttendee, 'userID': userID, 'imageBase64': imageBase64};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: ".../../../../Operation/insert.aspx/createEvent",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (result) {

                if (result.d <= 0) {
                    //false alert something 
                    alert("FALSE");
                }
                else if (result.d > 0) {
                    //true
                    alert(result.d);
                }
                else {
                    alert("sent but no call-back");
                }
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, errorthrown) {
                alert(" connection to the server failed ");
                console.log("error: " + errorthrown);
            }
        });

    }
```

Here's the Webmethod that will get the post

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string createEvent(string eventTitle, string eventDesc, string eventPlace, string eventType, string eventAttendee, string userID, string imageBase64)
{
    String orgID = (String)HttpContext.Current.Session["orgID"];
    string response = orgID;


    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Users/Organizer/organizerData/"); // de path


    //Check if directory exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path); //Create directory if it doesn't exist
    }


    string imageName = "event1" + ".jpg";// for instance

    //set the image path
    string imgPath = Path.Combine(path, imageName);

    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64);

    File.WriteAllBytes(imgPath, imageBytes); //write the file in the directory 


    return imageBase64;
}
```

Comment: You need to get the actuall Exception before we can help debugging. In particular we need: Type, Message and Stacktrace. Exception.ToString() is a easy way to get that. For security reasons, WebServers do not hand out Exception details in their HTML response. After all those might contain sensitive data like Logins. Or even stuff like SELECT query that just failed, wich is very valuable to get the Tablenames for SQL Injections.

Comment: I expect is has to do with the fact that a data URL may have more than just the file contents as Base64; it also can have the media type and the string ";base64,". See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). It could also be the standard problem outlined in [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/215552), since reading a file is asynchronous (`getBase64` returns undefined right now).